# How to calculate summation of a property in nested class structure in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have 3 classes, Class A, B, C. Class A contains List of Class B, Class B contains List Of Class C. Class C contains primitives.

```
class A {
    List<B> bList;
//getter
}

class B {
    List<C> cList;
//getter
}

class C {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
//getter
}
```

I want to do the following.

```
A aInstance = new A();
List<B>bs = aInstance.getBList();
for(B b: bs) {
        List<C> cs = b.getCList();
        for(C c: cs) {
            sum_a += c.a;
            sum_b_c += c.b + c.c;
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve this with java 8 specific streams ?

Comment: As you see using of `forEach` loop more readable than using of `stream`

Answer (score 2):

You could `reduce` that to an int array for example with two elements:

```
int[] result = aInstance
            .getBList()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(b -> b.getcList().stream())
            .map(c -> new int[] { c.a, c.b + c.c })
            .reduce((left, right) -> {
                int[] newV = new int[2];
                newV[0] = left[0] + right[0];
                newV[1] = left[1] + right[1];
                return newV;
            })
            .orElse(new int[] { 0, 0 });
```

Or even better via `collect` (not to create many `int []` objects):

```
int[] result = aInstance
            .getBList()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(b -> b.getCList().stream())
            .collect(
                    () -> new int[2],
                    (arr, c) -> {
                        arr[0] += c.a;
                        arr[1] += c.b + c.c;
                    }, 
                    (left, right) -> {
                        left[0] += left[0];
                        right[1] += right[1];
                    });
```

Comment: OP don't have `aList` just `aInstance`

Comment: well, you can not use `aInstance
            .stream()`.

Answer (score 2):

Well there should be a `flatMap` step and an appropriate accumulator used in the `collect` step, like:

```
int[] sums = a.bList.stream().flatMap(b -> b.cList.stream())
    .collect(() -> new int[2], (acc, v) -> {
               acc[0] += v.a;
               acc[1] += v.b + v.c;
             }, (acc, other) -> {
               acc[0] += other[0];
               acc[1] += other[1];
             });
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some type to hold the two sums, for example:

```
public class Sums {
    int sumA;
    int sumBC;
    public Sums (int sumA, int sumBC) {this.sumA=sumA; this.sumBC=sumBC;}
    public int getA() {return sumA;}
    public int getBC() {return sumBC;}
}
```

Now you create a `Stream` of the element you wish to sum and reduce it to a `Sums` instance:

```
Sums sums = aInstance.getBList()
                     .stream()
                     .flatMap(b->b.getCList().stream())
                     .reduce(new Sums(0,0),
                            (s,c)->new Sums(s.getA()+c.getA(),s.getBC()+c.getB()+c.getC()),
                            (s1,s2)->new Sums(s1.getA()+s2.getA(),s1.getBC()+s2.getBC()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use streams in this specific case as you don't gain anything from it. in fact, there is a lot more code when using a stream, not as readable as one might think and not as efficient as the imperative `for` loop.

So, I'd suggest you proceed with your current approach and in fact, you can reduce the code you currently have to:

```
for(B b: aInstance.getBList()) {
    for(C c: b.getCList()) {
       sum_a += c.a;
       sum_b_c += c.b + c.c;
    }
}
```

Comment: agree with you. `aInstance.getbList().forEach(b->b.getcList().forEach(c->{
            sum_a[0] +=c.a;
            sum_b_c[0] += c.b + c.c;
        }));`

Comment: @HadiJ I would not use the `forEach` though as that will force you to use an array for the summation of `c.a` and `c.b + c.c` which is unnecessary and can be avoided. instead, use an enhanced for loop as shown in my answer and then you only have to declare two variables before the outer loop for the summations.